# rails3 mysql2 GEM does not seem to do TCP, only socket

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems

What I am surmising is that mysql2 does not default to a TCP connection protocol when I remove the socket parameter. Do you guys agree?  Any GEM suggestions?

I can connect via the mysql command line.   So yep all configured from a mysql point of view.

This line connects nicely:  "mysql -P 3406 -u userid  -p --protocol=TCP -h localhost"
Enter password:

```
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 77402
Server version: 5.0.77-log Source distribution

Copyright (c) 2000, 2010, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.

Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its
affiliates. Other names may be trademarks of their respective
owners.

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.

mysql> show databases;
+---------------------+
| Database            |
+---------------------+
```

database.yml

```
svc_development:
    adapter: mysql2
    encoding: utf8
    database: my_db
    username: userid
    password: apasswd
    host: localhost
    port: 3406
```

The port is correct for this instance.  I am connecting to this database via SSH tunnel  "-L 3406:host:3306"
I looked at themysql2 code, it does not take a protocol parameter. It just uses socket.

Model:  looky_loo.rb

```
class LookyLoo < ActiveRecord::Base
    self.abstract_class = true
    establish_connection  "svc_development"
end
```

From Rails console

```
from script/rails:6:in `<main>'ruby-1.9.2-p136 :002 > LookyLoo.all
Mysql2::Error: Access denied for user 'userid'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
    from /Users/michael.pechner/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136@amqp/gems/mysql2-0.2.7/lib/mysql2/client.rb:42:in `connect'
    from /Users/michael.pechner/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136@amqp/gems/mysql2-0.2.7/lib/mysql2/client.rb:42:in `initialize'
    from /Users/michael.pechner/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136@amqp/gems/mysql2-0.2.7/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql2_adapter.rb:14:in `new'
    from /Users/michael.pechner/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136@amqp/gems/mysql2-0.2.7/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql2_adapter.rb:14:in `mysql2_connection'
    from /Users/michael.pechner/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136@amqp/gems/activerecord-3.0.5/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:229:in `new_connection'
```

Answer (score 32, accepted):

In mysql localhost is "magic" it means use the socket.  Try using 127.0.0.1 instead.

Comment: Excellent. This worked. Now the issue is that I have to tell the model the table name is not plural.

Comment: @mpecher just use set_table_name = "notpluralname" in your AR class

Comment: 9 years later and this answer totally helped me get unstuck!

Comment: strange, but 127.0.0.1 is not working for me

Comment: UPD: the issue was in the port. We should use port on local machine for SSH tunnel different than 3306. In this case mysql will try to use socket even if we specify 127.0.0.1